# Getting a Count from a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I'm having diffuculties trying to get a count. Currently It's displaying all the records But I would like a count Instead.

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
   {
   Items.AddRange(   
                  ctx.Interactions.Where(x => x.ActivityDate >= StartDateTo &&
                    x.ActivityDate <= EndDateTo && x.Indepth == true).Select(
                    x => new InteractionDTO()
                      {                              
                          Indepth = x.Indepth
                       }
                     )
                 );
    }
```

Comment: The `Count` method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: which field do want the count of?

Comment: .Count() should work. Apply this to a list of items and you should be good to go

Comment: Arguement Int is not assignable to to parameter type

Comment: I don't understand how the above code would even make use of a Count. You're got a collection called Items and you're trying to retrieve a bunch of items and add them to said collection. Where exactly does the count come into play here?

Comment: Are you trying to get a count and populate items at the same time?  `Items.Count()` would give it to you, or running  your `Where` again without the `Select` and adding a `.Count()` would do it also.

Comment: It may not be the best choice of methods. Tips on how to just get Count that would be swell. I'm Binding the Value to a Datagrid. Just this way I thought would work.

Comment: You are binding the `Count` to a Datagrid?

Comment: Yes, that is my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your current code, a count should be attainable by replacing "where" with "count" as demonstrated below.

```
return ctx.Interactions.Count(x => x.ActivityDate >= StartDateTo &&
                    x.ActivityDate <= EndDateTo && x.Indepth == true)
```

**UPDATE**: To preserve the binding then perhaps you should get the count off the collection you're adding to:

```
using (var ctx = DB.Get())
   {
   Items.AddRange(   
                  ctx.Interactions.Where(x => x.ActivityDate >= StartDateTo &&
                    x.ActivityDate <= EndDateTo && x.Indepth == true).Select(
                    x => new InteractionDTO()
                      {                              
                          Indepth = x.Indepth
                       }
                     )
                 );

int count = Items.Count();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't have Select Method after replacing where with Count

Comment: I apologize, it was a typo. I'm only trying to help.

Comment: I definitely like the approach you took, Alot cleaner than my approach. But now I lose my binding, how do I regain it using that method.